# Why did I get a 400 Bad Request when getting a page with PHP Curl?

Tags: php

I was trying to access a page using curl. I could access it perfectly using the browser and using "static" strings as the URL, like:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/?q=1234"
```

But when I tried to access the page using a variable in the URL string like:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/?q=$param"
```

I got a 400 error code. I checked out on the web and found some comments here in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466681/400-bad-request-when-getting-a-page-with-php-curl) stackoverflow thread:

Then, just for curiosity I did the following:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/?q=" . trim($param);
```

and it worked! And no, `$param` did NOT contain any spaces.

To me, it seems that it can be some encoding error, but I really can't find an explanation for it. Does anyone here in stackoverflow know what it can possibly be?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you're 100% sure it didn't contain a space, then `$param` probably contained one of the other characters `trim()` [cuts away with](http://de.php.net/trim):

> - "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> - "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> - "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> - "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> - "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

You could find out for sure by using [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php):

```
$string = "\nTEST\r";
for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string)-1;  $i++) 
 echo "(".ord($string[$i]).")";
```

this snippet will  output all character values in the string, including those of invisible characters:

```
 (10)(84)(69)(83)(84)(13)
```

the `10` beingh the newline character in the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the website reject external requests, so maybe try adding a referrer value as the website and a client browser value as firefox. maybe that can trick it and accept the request.

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is to echo out the $url variable after assignment.  That way you can see exactly what is in it.